# how to use insert method with select method in one query in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, mysqli

I am using this query.

```
$query = $this->db->query("INSERT INTO '".$tbl."' ('".$data."') 
         SELECT * FROM  '".$tbl."' ")->result();
```

Please suggest me proper query for the problem.

Comment: pls always response to the answers by giving some comments or ,if it helps you, by marking it as green and upvoting, it is the best way to thanks all the programmers

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :**

*You can do it by  selecting the  columns to be inserted first*

```
/*change your table name here*/
$table = 'users';

/*change your column column_name1 , column_name2 with your table column*/
$sql = 'INSERT into '.$table.' (column_name1, column_name2) 
        SELECT column_name1, column_name2 FROM '.$table;

$query = $this->db->query($sql);
```

Or you can use query builder like this :

```
/*change your table name here*/
$table = 'users';

$this->db->select('column_name1, column_name2');
$query = $this->db->get($table);
if ($query->num_rows() > 0)
{
    $this->db->insert($table, $query->row());
    /*for multiple rows use insert_batch()*/
}
```